# Perl Multi hash vs Single hash

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I want to read and process sets of input from a file and then print it out.
There are 3 keys which I need to use to store data.
Assume the 3 keys are `k1, k2, k3`

Which of the following will give better performance

```
$hash{k1}->{k2}->{k3} = $val;
```

or

```
$hash{"k1,k2,k3"} = $val;
```

For my previous question I got the answer that all perl hash keys are treated as strings.

Comment: Approximately how many keys will you have in each tier?

Comment: I will have minimum of 100 keys in each level..so in total 300 keys

Comment: You're prematurely optimizing. This will run in milliseconds.

Comment: Milliseconds, if not microseconds...

Comment: i think, that he ask about speed. in my porpose, hashes in perl are trees, so, if you want great speed, you need more layers of tree. correct me, if i'm wrong. (and also it depends on probability theory of keys incoming, so, it can't be, that all keys looks like {k1,k2,kn}, n>=3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hash lookup speed is independent of the number of items in the hash, so the version which only does one hash lookup will perform the hash lookup portion of the operation faster than the version which does three hash lookups.  But, on the other hand, the single-lookup version has to concatenate the three keys into a single string before they can be used as a combined key; if this string is anonymous (e.g., `$hash{"$a,$b,$c"}`), this will likely involve some fun stuff like memory allocation.  Overall, I would expect the concatenation to be quick enough that the one-lookup version would be faster than the three-lookup version in most cases, but the only way to know which is faster in *your* case would be to write the same code in both styles and [Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark) the difference.

However, like everyone else has already said, this is a premature and worthless micro-optimization.  Unless you know that you have a performance problem (or you have historical performance data which shows that a problem is developing and will be upon you in the near future) **and** you have profiled your code to determine that hash lookups are the cause of your performance problem, you're wasting your time worrying about this.  Hash lookups are *fast*.  It's hardly a real benchmark, but:

```
$ time perl -e '$foo{bar} for 1 .. 1_000_000'
real    0m0.089s
user    0m0.088s
sys 0m0.000s
```

In this trivial (and, admittedly, highly flawed) example, I got a rate equivalent to roughly 11 million hash lookups per second.  In the time you spent asking the question, your computer could have done hundreds of millions, if not *billions*, of hash lookups.

Write your hash lookups in whatever style is most readable and most maintainable in your application.  If you try to optimize this to be as fast as possible, the wasted programmer time will be (many!) orders of magnitude larger than any processing time that you could ever hope to save with the optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're really dealing with large datasets, use whichever one produces cleaner code. I may be wrong but this reeks of premature optimization.

If it isn't, this may depend on the range of possible keys. If ordering is not an issue, arrange your data in order so that `k1` is the smallest set of keys and `k3` is the largest. I suspect you'll use less memory on hashes that way. Depending on your datasets it may even be prudent to presize your hashes (I think `%hash = 100` does the trick).

As to which is faster, only profiling will tell. Try both and see for yourself.

Also, note that `$hash{k1}->{k2}-{k3}` is unnecessary. You can write `$hash{k1}{k2}{k3}`. Dereferences aren't needes *in between* brackets, either square or curly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have memory concerns I would suggest use `Devel::Size` from CPAN in a early fase of development to get the size of both alternatives. 
Otherwise use the one which seems friendly for you!